# Compile kernel module targeting different kernel version

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, make, linux-headers

I have a simple "hello world" Linux kernel module that I would like to compile for a different host. My host is on a 5.x kernel version and the target is on 4.x.

I do not want to update the kernel versions. This is a virtualized lab environment for testing purposes.

When the target kernel version's headers are in the repos, this is a straightforward task. All it usually takes is an `apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` or similar, followed by `make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules`. It doesn't seem so easy otherwise.

Even when attempting to download header packages manually from the [Debian archive](https://snapshot.debian.org/) I'm met with dependency issues with older binaries that I do not want to overwrite my up-to-date binaries with. I have even tried to compile against the full [Linux kernel source](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/) and have similar issues.

I have no experience building kernel modules except for simple ones using my own kernel's headers. Any help?

Answer (score -1):

You may need to adjust your environment variables to point to the version you downloaded with "full Linux kernel source"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).